# Expectation of the stopping time for certain random walk

Tags: probability, expected-value, random-walk, stopping-times

> Consider a random walk on $\mathbb Z^2 \subset \mathbb C$ starting from the orgin $(0,0)$. At each step, it randomly go one of the $4$ directions with length $1$ (i.e. $\pm 1, \pm \sqrt{-1}$). It stops if it hits one of the $4$ points $(\pm 5 ,\pm 5)$ in the first time. The question is, what is the expectation of the stopping time?

I can write down explicitly the number of paths of hitting any given point at the $k$-th step. Then the expectation can be written down as a summation of infinite sequences. However, I wonder if there is a simple expression, and I would like to know if there is a more elegant approach to this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Side observation: Although the expected stopping time is infinite as joriki shows in their answer, the probability of stopping is nevertheless $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expectation is infinite.

There is clearly a non-zero probability for the walk to reach $x=6$. Thus, if we can show that the expected time for it to get back to $x=5$ is infinite, it will follow that the desired expected first hitting time is also infinite. This, in turn, will follow if the same is true for a one-dimensional random walk, since the fact that we sometimes take steps in the $y$ direction in between only increases the expected time.

So consider a simple symmetric random walk in the $x$ direction. To obtain a contradiction, let $t$ be the finite expected time required for the walk to get back to $x=5$ from $x=6$. Then by translation invariance the expected time to get back to $x=6$ from $x=7$ is also $t$, and thus the expected time to get back to $x=5$ from $x=7$ is $2t$. Since the walk goes to $x=5$ and $x=7$ from $x=6$ with equal probability, this yields $t=1+\frac12(0+2t)=1+t$, a contradiction.

Comment: $+1$. Slight error? The time to return from $x = 6$ to $x = 5$, conditioned on going first to $x = 7$, is $1 + 2t$, since you need a step to get from $x = 6$ to $x = 7$ before embarking on the two $t$-trips. This leads to $t = [1+(1+2t)]/2 = 1+t$—still a contradiction, of course.

Comment: @BrianTung: True, thanks, fixed.